# How is one person in a set of twins referred to?

Tags: phrase-usage

This is kind of like "a pair of pants"; is one leg of the pants a "pant" - a left pant and a right pant make up a pair of pants?

Anyway, I'm thinking of twins. Is it right to say:

```
Jaclyn is a twin.
Jessica is a twin.
Jaclyn and Jessica are twins.
```

?

It doesn't seem right to me, because a "twin" means two, and one person can't be two people. It seems more accurate to say, "Jaclyn is one of a set of twins" - but admittedly, far more awkward than just saying that she is "a twin."

What is correct/accepted?

A perhaps related conundrum is that 0 is plural (so are negative quantities), whereas 1 is singular ("There are zero dollars in my wallet"; "there is one dollar in my wallet." If 0 is plural, why isn't 1?

...but if there is more than one 1, it *is* plural, to wit:

```
42 contains zero Zeros.
42 contains 42 ones.
-42 contains 21 -2s.
```

I'd better give it up; I'm starting to confuse myself...

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong with saying "I'm a twin": it's both grammatically and factually correct. (Well, in my case. For other people, it may only be grammatically correct.)

Comment: @Martha - I agree and I think that should be an answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: Clay, You have already said that the two people are *twins* (plural), or "a set of twins" (plural). Why should one of them **not** be "a twin"? *Twin* means "one of a pair", not "two". @Marthaª is right -- and the comment is the answer.

Comment: In fact, I would go so far as to say [a simple dictionary search](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twin) provides the answer, as well.

Comment: Dictionaries are so 20th Century.

Comment: _Twin_ (n) is a count noun derived from the PIE root for 'two'. This does not imply that _twin_ ***means*** 'two'. The singular is _(a/`P's) twin_; the plural is actually a dual, so one speaks of _twins, a pair of twins, both twins,_ etc, using dual quantifiers if necessary to include both people in a twin relation. There is also a causative verb _twin_ meaning 'to duplicate', used in special contexts and speech communities. The noun _twin_ participates in many dual idioms and place names: _Twin Cities, twin towers, twin bed, Twin Forks,_ etc.

Comment: *Twin* does not mean two. *Twins* are two; *twin* is one member of a pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Martha is right about a twin.

Re your other question:

> 42 contains zero Zeros.
>  42 contains 42 ones.
>   -42 contains 21 -2s.

In each case the first numbers (zero/42/21) 
are effectively acting as adjectives describing the second numbers (Zeros/ones/-2s) which are nouns.

Imagine you are playing cards and someone asks you:
"How many fives do you have?"
You reply "I have two fives."

Here "five" is the name of the card with five dots on it. It is a noun, and takes a plural 's' like most nouns.

But as to why we say *zero dollars* (plural), I've no idea.

Comment: We also say "0.1 dollars." Any number besides 1 is plural, generally. But a tricky case is"-1": I was just discussing this with my family, and while I prefer "-1 dollars," my mother prefers "-1 dollar."

Comment: Poor answer. The first line is meaningless when or if Martha or a mod one day decides to delete the comment. Why not quote it verbatim?